# Image disappears in Google maps full screen display

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I have a  with a logo that appears in the lower right corner of map near the controls. The problem is that when the full screen option is selected the logo disappears. The div (aggdata-info) appears to be there when I look at it in firebug but the image/logo is not visible. Any ideas?

```js
initMap : function() {
   var me = this;

   me.map.mapOptions = {
     zoom : 4,
     center : {
      lat: 37.6,
      lng: -95.665
     },
     mapTypeControlOptions : {
      mapTypeIds : [
       //'map_style',
       google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
       google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
       google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
      ]
     },
     //mapTypeId : 'map_style',
     
     zoomControl : true,
     mapTypeControl : true,
     scaleControl : false,
     streetViewControl : true,
     rotateControl : true,
     fullscreenControl : true,
     fullscreenControlOptions : {
      position : google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM
     }
     
    };
```

```css
div.aggdata-info {
 height: 38px;
 width: 170px;
 text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
 background: #fff url(../cmnimages/reit_common/data_by_aggdata.png) center center no-repeat;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 font-size: 12px;
 position: absolute;
    margin-top: 493px;
    margin-left: 832px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}
```

[Standard size with logo included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj7JF.png)
[Full screen logo disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eEjI.jpg)

Below is the css for that div.

Comment: Please can you share your javascript/jquery code here or jsfiddle? So it's better to understand.

Comment: Added the javascript code

Comment: Please check my Answer.

Comment: Does this thing is working well for you or not?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow my code and sorry i never used your code!.I did all the changes in my code.

**Note:** I have included js file in that file you need to add your **google API key** otherwise google map display below error.:

Google Maps API error: InvalidKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key-map-error.

Using this `disableDefaultUI: true` i just hide object in google map and it is also possible to hide particular object in google map.

**If you wanted to use edit your code then and this below code.**

```
var customControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var customControl = new CustomControl(customControlDiv, map);
customControlDiv.index = 1;
```

**and function**

```
function CustomControl(controlDiv, map) {
            var tempBackgroundImage = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/W/0/g/a/W/E/map-pin-red-md.png";
            controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
            controlDiv.style.right = '5px';
            var myLocationControlDiv = document.createElement('DIV');

            var controlUI = document.createElement('DIV');
            controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            controlUI.style.background = "url(" + tempBackgroundImage + ") 68px 78px";
            controlUI.style.height = '68px';
            controlUI.style.width = '68px';
            controlUI.style.right = '15px';
            controlUI.style.bottom = '50px';
            controlUI.style.backgroundSize= '68px 78px';
            controlUI.title = 'Current location';

            myLocationControlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(controlUI);

    }
```

That's it!!!

**You can use below whole code if you are not using your code.**

**Html**

```js
 var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8,
          disableDefaultUI: true
        });
        var customControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var customControl = new CustomControl(customControlDiv, map);

        customControlDiv.index = 1;
      }
      function CustomControl(controlDiv, map) {
   var tempBackgroundImage = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/W/0/g/a/W/E/map-pin-red-md.png";
   controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
   controlDiv.style.right = '5px';
   var myLocationControlDiv = document.createElement('DIV');

   var controlUI = document.createElement('DIV');
   controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
   controlUI.style.background = "url(" + tempBackgroundImage + ") 68px 78px";
   controlUI.style.height = '68px';
   controlUI.style.width = '68px';
   controlUI.style.right = '15px';
   controlUI.style.bottom = '50px';
   controlUI.style.backgroundSize= '68px 78px';
   controlUI.title = 'Current location';

   myLocationControlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
   map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(controlUI);

 }
```

```css
 /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

**Important thing:**

Please update below values according to image size.

```
controlUI.style.height = '68px';
controlUI.style.width = '68px';
controlUI.style.backgroundSize= '68px 78px';
```

Comment: Can I put this in a separate script to run or do I need to integrate this into my code?

Comment: If it's possible then integrate with your code. Please add this code : var customControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var customControl = new CustomControl(customControlDiv, map);
customControlDiv.index = 1; and this function CustomControl() code into your code.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: deleted  the comment.

Comment: Working fine as a standalone page, but when I move the code into my content I get a : Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at new CustomControl (reit_map.cfm:826)
    at callback (reit_map.cfm:857)

Comment: The common error is this line: var customControl = new CustomControl(customControlDiv, map); map not defined

Comment: See above edited code for the initMap statement. Error is occurring when I attempt the place it there

Comment: Instead of map you need to pass your object i think this me.map.mapOptions.